# Is there a performance impact to having docker containers with different OS base boxes?

Tags: linux, docker, operating-system, dockerfile

When building a docker container, we choose a container to inherit from, which is often a Linux OS (like ubuntu, debian or boot2docker). Does it have a performance impact whether multiple containers running on the same host share the same parent OS box?

[A great answer would explain why the answer is the case, whether elements of the OS are shared between separate containers and any best practices around choosing what dependencies to use when building docker containers.]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes for disk space, maybe for RAM.

Docker uses a *union filesystem*, which allows containers based on the same images to share files, until a file is modified at which point it is duplicated. (This is called *copy-on-write*.) So using the same base images will save you some disk space. Of course, disk space is rarely a limiting factor these days, so I usually wouldn't consider that a "performance impact".

Meanwhile, *some* of the Docker storage drivers—aufs and OverlayFS, but not btrfs and devicemapper—lead to certain shared libraries being shared in RAM. So if you have multiple containers based on the same image, they won't load duplicate copies of e.g. libc in RAM, which if you have lots and lots of containers could make a difference. (Source: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.docker.devel/1385)